# Como mudar a versão do gradlew pela linha de comando?

Tags: gradle, linha-de-comando

Preciso reverter a versão do `gradlew` de volta para a 4.10.2. Fui para a versão 5.5.2 para fazer alguns testes e preciso retornar à versão original para confirmar os resultados dos testes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta digitar

```bsh
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=<VERSION>
```

que o `gradlew` irá se configurar para usar a versão descrita em `<VERSION>`. Na próxima vez que for rodar o `./gradlew`, ele irá fazer o download necessário e se levantará corretamente:

```
$ ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=4.10.2

> Configure project :app
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
1 actionable task: 1 executed

$ ./gradlew clean
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-bin.zip
..........................................................................
```

---

Se por acaso você mudar para uma versão inválida (como 5.5.2), o comando `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=<VERSION>` será aceito sem alertas. Porém, na próxima vez que for executar algum comando do `gradle`, acarretará no seguinte:

```
$ ./gradlew clean
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5.2-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-5.5.2-bin.zip
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:67)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:52)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
```

Inclusive o comando de mudar de versão!!

Para resolver isso, altere na mão o arquivo `./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. Por exemplo, o meu ficou assim após inserir a versão inválida:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Basta alterar a `distributionUrl` para algo válido. Normalmente esse arquivo está no sistema de versionamento, então bastaria voltar para a instância anterior dele. Caso contrário, use uma versão conhecida (como `5.5`, `5.5.1`, `4.10.2`...):

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```