# Como mudar a versão do mvnw pela linha de comando?

Tags: maven, linha-de-comando

Preciso alterar a versão do `mvnw` para a `3.5.0` ou superior. Estou usando um `maven-wrapper` herdado de outro projeto (copiado e colado), porém ele está na versão `3.3.9`.

Como fazer essa mudança na linha de comando?

> Estou fazendo essa questão como um apoio ao último parágrafo [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/421289/64969), pois é mais fácil manipular o `maven-wrapper` do que a instalação local do Maven
>
> Questão propositadamente semelhante à [esta sobre `gradlew`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/401933/64969)

Comment: Não adianta spammar perguntas agora...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta invocar o [`maven-wrapper-plugin`](https://github.com/takari/takari-maven-plugin). Peguei do [tutorial da Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wrapper) a seguinte linha:

```bsh
$ mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper -Dmaven=3.5.2

....

[INFO] --- maven:0.7.6:wrapper (default-cli) @ project ---
[INFO]
[INFO] Maven Wrapper version 0.5.5 has been successfully set up for your project.
[INFO] Using Apache Maven: 3.5.2
[INFO] Repo URL in properties file: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.722 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-13T16:01:22-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Com isso, foi alterada a versão do `mvnw` para `3.5.2`. O `git diff` identifica essa alteração também:

```bsh
$ git diff

diff --git a/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar b/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
index 5fd4d50..0d5e649 100644
Binary files a/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar and b/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar differ
diff --git a/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties b/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties
index c954cec..cc805cc 100644
--- a/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties
+++ b/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-distributionUrl=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.3.9/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip
+distributionUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.5.2/apache-maven-3.5.2-bin.zip
+wrapperUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/takari/maven-wrapper/0.5.5/maven-wrapper-0.5.5.jar
... [outras coisas do meu repositório que foram alteradas] ...
```